# Strange multi-processing trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, mathematical-optimization

Sorry for the vague title, but since I have no clue what the reason for my problem might be I don't know how to describe it better. Anyway, I have a strange problem in connection with multiprocessing and hope some of you can help me.

I'm currently dealing with convex optimization, especially with parallelizing the tasks. My goal is to utilize as many cores as possible on a multi-core-machine (on which I get access only temporarily).

Therefore, I took a look on the [CVXPY's Tutorial page](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html#changing-the-problem) and tried to implement an easy example to get into the topic (scroll down, it's the last example on the page). I shortened the example to the parts which are necessary for my question, so my code looks as follows:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy
from multiprocessing import Pool


# Assign a value to gamma and find the optimal x.
def get_x(gamma_value):
    print("E")
    gamma.value = gamma_value
    result = prob.solve()
    print("F")
    return x.value

# Problem data.
n = 15
m = 10
numpy.random.seed(1)
A = numpy.random.randn(n, m)
b = numpy.random.randn(n)
# gamma must be nonnegative due to DCP rules.
gamma = cp.Parameter(nonneg=True)

# Construct the problem.
x = cp.Variable(m)
error = cp.sum_squares(A @ x - b)
obj = cp.Minimize(error + gamma*cp.norm(x, 1))
prob = cp.Problem(obj)

# Construct a trade-off curve of ||Ax-b||^2 vs. ||x||_1
sq_penalty = []
l1_penalty = []
x_values = []
print("A")
gamma_vals = numpy.logspace(-4,6, num = 6400)

print("B")
for val in gamma_vals:
    gamma.value = val  

print("C")    

# Parallel computation (set to 1 process here).
pool = Pool(processes = 1)
print("D")
x_values = pool.map(get_x, gamma_vals)    

print(x_values[-1])
```

As you might have observed, I added some prints with capital letters, they served to find out where exactly the issue occurs, so I can refer to them in my problem description;

When I run the code the code processes and the letters "A" to "D" are displayed on the screen, so everything's fine until passing "D". But then the program kind of gets stuck. The CPU load is still high, so there definitely is going on something, but the code never reaches capital "E", which would be after successfully starting

```
x_values = pool.map(get_x, gamma_vals).
```

In my eyes it looks a bit like being stuck in an infinite loop.
Therefore, I guess someting with this pool.map function must be fishy. First, I thought that calling this function might be time-consuming and therefore it takes long to process (but that's rubbish, the optimization starts within the get_x function, so no reasoning).

Nevertheless, I tried to run my program on the multi-core-machine (with multiple cores, as well as with only a single core) and - surprise - it successfully passed this line nearly instantaneous and started with the actual optimization problem (and finally solved it).

So my issue is, that I don't know what's going wrong on my computer and how to fix it.

I can't access the machine at any time so - of course - I want to try the code on my computer first before uploading it, which isn't possible if even this easy toy-example doesn't work.

I' be grateful for any ideas/help!

Thank you in advance!

FOOTNOTE: I am using WIN10, the multi-core machine uses Linux

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: are your machine and the multi-core-machine the same OS/version of python? BTW If you're on Windows you need to protect the "main" code with `if __name__=='__main__':` see the multiprocessing documentation

Comment: Putting your executable code at module level means this won't work for spawn based multiprocessing like Windows. Put that module level code under an `if __name__ == "__main__:` block.

Comment: _In my eyes it looks a bit like being stuck in an infinite loop._ In Windows, the module is reimported the the spawned process and so its top level code will run again, causing a new import and run, and etc...

Comment: Off-topic: i would not even bother with this kind of parallelization (error-prone and inefficient). While solving a problem like this / or general machine-learning like problem (ok it might only be an example) with general-purpose solvers (as used here) is highly inefficient, those solvers (and usually also the more efficient alternatives) are usually fully parallelized in it's core (and additional outer parallelization will only hurt!). This kind of parallelization is relatively easy in IPM=ECOS/ADMM=SCS solvers. SCS can even run on the GPU. I would first check my solvers for this.

Comment: @AMC, barny, tdelaney oh that must be the issue! I haven't been able to run the code after adding this if - line since then variables in the function are unknown and it looks like pool.map can only handle one input argument, so I have to do think a bit to make the toy example working. Thank's for your hints!

Comment: @sascha Your comment definitely hits the bull's eye. I definitely need to speed up my optimization task, so my first idea was to use the parallelization-option for CVX and MOSEK-solver. Unfortunately, this didn't improve anything, so - if I can't speed up the process itself I thought it might be a good plan B to solve the optimization problem for as many parameters as possible in parallel. I would definitely prefer to speed up the process itself. I haven't tried SCS (which should be suitable for my task), but CVX and MOSEK. Is SCS better in "internal" multi-processing than the others?

Comment: Implementation-wise surely not as advanced as mosek (one man vs. full company). But SCS is a very different solver conceptionally and should scale better with big instances (while approaching less accurate solutions). For some problems, SCS can be an alternative, for others not. But ML-like sizes probably more in SCS domain than Mosek.